# The URL canvas of a Facebook app redirects to my own: developed in CakePHP

Tags: php, facebook, session, cakephp, authentication

I've developed a Facebook app (with iframe) using CakePHP. I get some Facebook user info when the app opens and display a form to send SMS free.

So, the user must be authenticated in Facebook before continuing in the app.

I'm using the Facebook SDK php (Copyright 2004-2008 Facebook. All Rights Reserved.)

How could I avoid Facebook to redirect to my own site when the user has lost the auth session?

Answer (score 0):

Are you having the user use the FB login popups, and the FB authorization code?

Not sure if this will work for your situation, but on the loginURL code, you can pass in a redirect_uri that could point to a page that you want them forwarded to after they complete the login and the authentication procedure.

```
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'offline_access,publish_stream,email',
                    'redirect_uri'=>'https://www.mysite.com/mysite/'));
```

Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I want that he/she stay in the fb site using my app in side the canvas. For example my canvas URL is:
http://apps.facebook.com/fbsmscuba/
and my own URL is:
http://fbcuballama.coordenadaslatinas.com/fbusers/

The user is redirect from the fb to my own URL when session has expired.... I want that he/she stay using my app in facebook canvas

Comment: You're looking for the user to stay in the "apps.facebook.com/fbsmscuba" after the auth?  I would expect that the redirect_uri parameter gives you that.  If not, then that would be something that FB would be doing.  Not sure how to fix that up.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue, that with the new https and iframe configuration from FB in an app, when the user submits a form, it's going from the apps.facebook.com/myapp to my server outside of FB.  I understand the problem, but haven't discovered the solution just yet.

Comment: I've downloaded and tested the following example: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/

...and the issue continue... once the user is logon in facebook, he/she is redirect to the own site... he/she doesn't stay in the facebook URL... this is weird...

Answer (score 0):

I understand everything in the question except the last line.  What do you mean by:

> How could I avoid Facebook to redirect to my own site when the user has lost the auth session?

If you are using facebook for login credentials, then you are required to redirect to your own site.  This is a facebook security rule and you can imagine why it exists.

For anything fancy, you'll want to use the facebook "server-side" flow.  It's fairly straight forward:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/